# What is the 1/2 spin analog of the graviton called?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, supersymmetry, terminology

In some supergravities you have the gravition, gravitino, graviphoton and graviscalar. Each is analogous to each other in only sharing gravitational properties and nothing else.  They differ by spin in the order of 2, 3/2, 1 and 0.  What is the spin 1/2 analogue named?

Comment: Um, graviphotino?

Comment: *Is* there a predicted spin-1/2 graviton particle?